# Angularjs rootscope data loss in refreshing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i got a situation in angularjs1.x
when i am save a value in   `$rootScope` after pass the next page/router

The `$rootScope` value is lost in  Refresh f5/reload (window reload)

without using localStorage

Comment: am not completely satisfied with the answer to this question, my question is, why I can't store into $rootScope.

Answer (score 0):

Basically refreshing the page will wipe your $rootscope from memory (basically your entire app will be 'restarted').

In order to persist values you must store your value somewhere, you can use either localStorage/sessionStorage.

for example :

```
localStorage.setItem("yourKey", "YourValue");
```

and you can get it after page refreshed like :

```
localStorage.getItem("yourKey")// YourValue
```

read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: how i manage this problem without using localStorage

Comment: @MUJEEB Your other option is sessionStorage , Anyway you need to use one of them in case of stroring your values after page refreshed.

Comment: Degnavi -  am not completely satisfied with the answer to this question, my question is, why I can't store into $rootScope.

Comment: @MUJEEB If you refresh your page, you will lose your $rootScope data,  that's for sure, $rootScope is not a database or some magic tools to save your data when you refresh the page, if you refresh, everything will reset, including your $rootScope. if you change the route only, you will have your data, but REFRESH a page, will reset all your scopes. so you have to use other options, like sessionStorage, or localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid that by using `localStorage` to store your data.

```js
$rootScope.data = localStorage.data; // get data from localStorage and assign it to rootScope
var data = {a : 1, b: 2}; // update your data
localStorage.data = data; // set it in localStorage
$rootScope.data = data;
```

**Note** You'll need to update your `localStroage` data every time you update `$rootScope.data` .

Comment: how i manage this problem without using localStorage

Comment: @MUJEEB  You need to store your data in some place. you can choose anything you want. `localStorage` , `sessionStorage` ... etc

Comment: am not completely satisfied with the answer to this question, my question is, why I can't store into $rootScope.